# Id of menuitem is not rendered

Tags: primefaces

After upgrading application from primefaces 3.4.2 to primefaces-4.0.jar, `p:menuitem`   doesn't have it's `id` field.

This is the code I have

```
 <h:form id="menuform">
 <p:menuitem id="A" value="value1" url="#" />
```

Under 4.0:

```
 <a tabIndex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="#">
 <span class="ui-menuitem-text">value1</span></a>
```

Under 3.4.2:

```
<a class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" id="menuform:A" href="#">
<span class="ui-menuitem-text">value1</span></a>
```

Due to this I am getting undefined or null reference script error while getting the menu item component id later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PrimeFaces bug.
I already opened an Issue #1039 because of that problem with more details.
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1039
Upcote it if you like.

Comment: I posted a workaround over here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154557/setting-id-for-a-dynamic-menu-element-in-primefaces-does-not-work/41551063#41551063